# ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest when adding new springdoc version

Tags: java, spring, maven, dependencies, springdoc

I have a Springboot 3.0.1 API for which I'm triyng to add

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

To, but it results in `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest`.

I removed other springdoc related dependencies from the project I'm trying to run springdoc in. I am not sure what else could be the issue. It could be that one of the other projects that this project depends on is causing the issue, but I am not sure how to solve it

[Output of dependency tree](https://pastebin.com/ScdRhbyw)

Comment: Just adding a dependency won't result in an exception. Share your whole problem including any relevant code and error messages.

Comment: My guess: this dependency (or whatever else) depends on old javax.* instead of the new `jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest`

Comment: @Jorn [this](https://pastebin.com/NJdj5yPy) is the full stack trace. It appears when I start the app and it happens when I try to use this dependency.

Comment: You are using Spring Framework 6, which depends on jakarta as enterprise library and thus doesn't have javax on its classpath. I don't know this dependency, but it seems that it's outdated for new Spring projects.